# retreive JSON data from a website using a string instead of a URL

Tags: objective-c, json

I would like to retrieve JSON data from a website, but the user would be able to enter a URL. I tried using

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
```

and to define `getDataURL` I used

```
#define getDataURL @"http://..."
```

This works but I can't change the URL. Is their a way to do what I need ?

Comment: What kind of application are you creating? Is it for iOS or OS X? You have to provide more information. I assume you have to create a text field where the user can type the URL and then read the value of the field at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a string constant, but you can get the string from anywhere. If you want the user to enter the string, you can use a text field in your user interface and let the user type the URL there. Then you'll get the URL:

```
NSString* getDataUrl = theTextField.text;
```

Comment: to save the content of the textfield I used a .plist file. then, I read that file and retrieve the url in a variable name "array" do I did     NSString* getDataUrl = array;    and then    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataUrl];    but then when I run I get a "signal sigabrt" in here :    "citiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    
    if([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
...} " Thanks for your help !

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different question from the one here. You should really start a separate post and not try to address it in comments. More information will help, but before you post dig in and see if you can't solve the problem yourself.